# Recursive method to return number of zeroes

Tags: java, recursion

This is from an old test that I'm using to study.
I need to write a recursive method that returns the number of zeroes on the int[] from position 0 and right.
given int numberOfZeroes(int[] a, int right);

Comment: "from position 0 and right" - do you mean "between position 0 and `right`"?

Comment: Ok.  So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you give an example of input and output? The description is a touch confusing.

Comment: @schnaader, yes, between int 0 and int right.

Comment: A Oli, I know it would be easy to do it with a for/while loop, but don't know how to do it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes `right < a.length`

```
int numberOfZeroes(int[] a, int right) {
  if(right < 0) {  // We've gone through all indices
    return 0;  // So we don't want to recurse anymore
  } else if(a[right] == 0) {  // The current index has a zero
    return 1 + numberOfZeroes(a, right - 1); // Call the function, moving left one. Add one to the returned count since we found a zero
  } else {  // The current index does not have a zero
    return numberOfZeroes(a, right - 1); // Call the function, moving left one. We don't add anything since we didn't find a zero
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberOfZeroes(int[] a, int right) {
     if (right == 0) return 0;
     return numberOfZeros(a, right-1) + a[right] == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Do numberOfZeros(a, a.length) to get the number of zeros in the entire array.